# Mechanisms of protecting Judaism from misuse

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, theology

As we can see with Nazi Germany, democracy can be a dangerous thing. Many countries try to override democracy with a special status of the supreme court, able to invalidate the parliamentary laws (to some extent, as in current day Israel).

(This is a very discussed topic in Israel just before the 2019 elections).

Regular people and Rabbis with them can blindly follow false-prophets, false-Moshiachs, and false-Rabbis, each presenting his own interpretations to the existing sacred texts.

So if a person comes and declares himself as G-d-sent / Ruach Hakodesh or whatever and commands on breaking the basic laws of Judaism (Shabbos, Taharas Mishpachah and so on) by either claiming "עת לעשות לה'" or "הוראת שעה" or even (mis)-interpreting the Torah and causing the current Gdoylim to agree and join him, and we do "עשית ככל אשר יורוך"...

Is there a mechanism in Judaism for protecting it from such a misuse?

*The question is intentionally not about personal behavior (should you follow or not), but about the existence of such mechanisms.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/91882).

Comment: @AlBerko Sorry, what is “ASAIR”?

Comment: *Is there a mechanism in Judaism for protecting it from such a misuse ?* - Yes. Divine intervention. Moses in pagan Egypt, Elijah in times of Baal worship, Daniel and his three companions during the Captivity, the Maccabees in the Hellenistic era. God is a living God (Jeremiah 10:10).

Comment: @Lucian Seemingly G-d agreed that לא בשמים היא. Who's keeping it from turning into ... something else, like Christianity and Islam did?

Comment: ***Who** is keeping it from turning into something else ?* - God. :-) You did well by asking *who*, rather than *what*. It is indeed true that there are more [earthy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_in_Heaven) approaches (which Christianity and Islam also possess, by the way); nevertheless, your initial question seems to describe a situation of widespread apostasy, where almost all obedience on almost all levels appears to have ceased, implying that the well-known earthy approach did not, for one reason or another, suffice.